# Podman - rootless traefik should find other rootless containers spawned by other users

Tags: traefik, podman

I am working my way into Podman and have a question about whether the theoretical construct is possible.

**Target**
Rootless started traefik should find other rootless containers started with different users.

I've already searched the internet for a few hours, but haven't found an answer/approach.

**Attachment**
There are 3 users: system stack and overflow.
system starts traefik container rootless
stack starts nginx container rootless
overflow starts wordpress container rootless

**Challenge**
What are the options for traefik to find the containers (nginx and wordpress)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rootless podman has zero visibility of other podman users. That's why we run it in rootless mode -- to provide isolation that's not available when running as `root`. You're not going to be able to perform automatic discovery services when spreading your execution across three different users.

If you want to use Traefik and automatic service discovery, you'll need to run all your containers under the same user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, then I will (have to) implement it that way. I thought under some circumstances it would work if I could use some kind of network overlay technique. So a (default) network, what all other (authorized) containers could also see. But as you noted, that would probably violate the concept of isolation.

Comment: Correct answer! Just wanted to add that if you need different podman users you can of course let them communicate over a socket (or even a network socket if they run on different host machines). Service discoverability is generally a problem with rootless. If they are on the same podman network DNS works fine but if I f.e. add a container later on might need to restart traefik